# How to Change the content of Facebook Share Option, PHP

Tags: php, facebook

I am creating a PHP web application, that has Facebook Share Functionality, the basic function of it is the share content usually shares the whole website, and the contents itself,
how do I change the content of the Facebook Share instead of using the content from the Home page? My codes are basic as it was in Facebook Developers. The application actually makes a transaction, and after the transaction has succeeded, I've added a share button, so I want to share the content of the successful transaction not the whole website itself. Thanks

Here are my codes I got from old FB Share option:

```
<a name="fb_share" type="button" share_url="https://www.1123.com/tl">
##Share on Facebook## </a>
<script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

Comment: Can you post the code for your share button?

Comment: I have edited the question above for the codes.

Answer (score 0):

> so I want to share the content of the successful transaction not the whole website itself.

Set up an URL where the data of that transaction is accessible, and put meaningful [Open Graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) meta elements into that page.

And maybe you’d like to not only share your transaction as a link, but also define it as an [*object*](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/define-objects/) and have your users publish [*actions*](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/define-actions/) on these transaction objects …

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest continuing to learn about working with the Graph API and moving on to [Like](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) buttons.  Your goal is to supply specific data about the item you are attempting to share.